# Is staubert a slang term for stylish? And what is its origin?

Tags: etymology, slang

A listener to [Words to the Wise](http://wtcmradio.com/words-to-the-wise/) [[audio at wtcmradio.com](http://wtcmradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/WORDS1006.mp3)] shared that his family used the word staubert to describe something stylish, such as a new suit. I speculate that it is derived from the surname St. Aubert, but I have no proof. Any thoughts?

October 6, 2015 around 24:10. The other family word shared by the same caller was larrapin (tasty), which is confirmed by DARE, which leads me to think that it may not be the creation of one family only.

Comment: The actual page is http://wtcmradio.com/words-to-the-wise/. Please can you tell us which of the broadcasts it is (by date) and also say the time where the word is spoken?  It would help us because then we could listen to the actual conversation.

Comment: One family's use does not normally confer wordness in English.

Comment: October 6, 2015 at 24:10. The other half of his question involved the family use of larrapin (tasty) which is confirmed by DARE, so it may not be sui generis.

Comment: I clearly hear them saying 'stalbert'  rather than 'staubert'.  However that is just as meaningless as far as I am concerned. I don't see it as having anything to do with St. Albert either!  I notice that the caller was unable to spell it and I suspect he misheard it as a child. I don't know what it could be though. The only word it reminds me of is 'stalwart' but that has nothing to do with suits.

Comment: Direct link to the audio: http://wtcmradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/WORDS1006.mp3

Comment: I don't have any information on _staubert_ (or more likely _stalbert_). But I am familiar with _larruping_ (_larrapin_ is a variant spelling)—and defining it as meaning "tasty" is somewhat off the mark. The word originated from the verb _larrup_ meaning "to whip, thrash, or beat," and it is (or was, 70 years ago) used widely in the United States to convey the general meaning "good" or "very," according to Harold Wentworth, _American Dialect Dictionary_ (1944).